# Using group_by with fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a the following rails models:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :release_questionnaires, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :release_questionnaires
    ...
end class

class ReleaseQuestionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :release
    belongs_to :milestone
    ...
end class
```

In my view code, I have the following form.

```
<% form_for @release, ... do |f| %>
  ...
  <table class="questionnaires">
    <% f.fields_for :release_questionnaires, @release.release_questionnaires.sort_by{|ra| ra.questionnaire.name} do |builder| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

This works and allows me to view and edit the questionnaires as desired.  However, I have an additional requirement to break the questionnaires out into their own tables grouped by the milestone they are associated to, rather than in a single table. It appears as though the group_by method is design to accomplish this, but I cannot get it to work as desired inside the  tag.

It may be that I'm missing something obvious, as I am a beginner... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<% form_for @release, ... do |f| %>
  ...
  <% @release.release_questionnaires.group_by {|rq| rq.milestone }.each do |milestone, questionnaires_group| %>
    <table class="questionnaires">
      <% f.fields_for :release_questionnaires, questionnaires_group.sort_by{|rq| rq.name} do |builder| %>
        ...
      <% end %>
    </table>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes - that's it.  Sometimes it can be difficult to see the forest for the trees.  Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: How does this work?  How does rails group_by milestone...when the milestone isn't yet associated to the release_questionnaire?  I ask because I had this working in my own app, and it suddenly stopped working because it can no find 'milestone' to group or sort by.  The release questionnaire doesnt exist yet, and therefor neither does the milestone....so, how could it know how to group by it?  (for simplicity Im using the attribute names from this example)